# Only getting error from ESP8266 AT commands

Tags: esp8266, arduino-due

I am trying to get the ESP8266 work with Arduino AT commands. I am using the due. How do I get the ESP8266 to respond with anything other than ERROR?

Here is the current serial output:

```
AT
ERROR
```

Here is my code:

```C
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);     
    Serial3.begin(115200); //Manufacture said this is the correct baud rate      
}

void loop() {
    if ( Serial3.available() ) {  Serial.write( Serial3.read() );  }

    if ( Serial.available() )  {  Serial3.write( Serial.read() );  }
}
```

Here are my pin connections:

```
RX3  -> ESP TX
TX3  -> ESP RX
GND  -> GND
3.3V -> CH_PD + VCC
```

Comment: do you have CR/LF set in Serial Monitor?

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068) You also [asked this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49145463).

Comment: I didn't have CR/LF set. That fixed my problem

Answer (score 7):

The AT firmware responded with ERROR because it received data, but timed out waiting for the CR/LF line ending.

AT commands must be terminated with Carriage Return '\r' and Line Feed '\n' control bytes/characters.